# Why is my while loop only returning one value from the database?

Tags: php, mysql, html

PHP

```
$nextday = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Tour_Dates WHERE DATEDIFF( tourDate, NOW() ) > 0 ORDER BY tourDate LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());
$upcomingdates = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Tour_Dates WHERE DATEDIFF( tourDate, NOW() ) > 0 ORDER BY tourDate")or die(mysql_error());
$passeddates = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Tour_Dates WHERE DATEDIFF( tourDate, NOW() ) < 0 ORDER BY tourDate")or die(mysql_error());
```

HTML

```
<label class="next-day"><? while($row = mysql_fetch_array($nextday)){echo $row['city'] ."  |  " .date("m.d.Y",strtotime($row['tourDate']));} ?></label>

<div class="upcoming">
<ul>
<?
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($upcomingdates))
{
echo '<li><span class="li-date">'. date("m.d.Y",strtotime($row['tourDate'])) .'</span><span class="li-address">' . $row['address'] . '</span><span class="li-city">' . $row['city'] . '</span><span class="li-time">' . date("g.i A",strtotime($row['tourTime'])).'</span></li>';
}
?>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="passed">
<ul>
<?
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($passeddates))
{
echo '<li><span class="li-date">'. date("m.d.Y",strtotime($row['tourDate'])) .'</span><span class="li-address">' . $row['address'] . '</span><span class="li-city">' . $row['city'] . '</span><span class="li-time">' . date("g.i A",strtotime($row['tourTime'])).'</span></li>';
}
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the query returns more than one value?

Comment: it was working but now its only returning one thing. I have 3 things in the database right now. Do you have any other way that i could do this? I'm not sure how to turn this into a foreach loop

Comment: Hmm, the code looks okay so far. You are aware of the `LIMIT 1` in your query?

Comment: Yes the limit 1 was for something else. That shouldn't have affected the $upcomingdates or the $passeddates right? I'm only applying LIMIT 1 to the $nextday

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're using mysql_fetch_array, but then referencing the element as though it were an associative array. Try using one of the following:

```
mysql_fetch_array($upcomingdates, MYSQL_ASSOC)
```

or

```
mysql_fetch_assoc($upcomingdates)
```

Comment: Fixed! Something must have been weird with how my database was set up. I recreated it and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Dropped the table in the database and re-inserted it and everything was working again! I guess something went wrong the first time I imported it.